# Why am I getting 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I am trying to create a typing effect using vanilla JS, but for some reason I keep getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` error. I don't understand why though, as 'word' is defined. It's been bugging me for a while and I'm the type of person who likes to try to get the answer right on my own, but I'm completely stuck.

```js
var sentence = document.getElementsByClassName('sentence')[0];
var words = ['websites', 'apps', 'games'];
var speed = 100;
var i = 0;
var j = 0;

function type(word) {
 if(i<word.length) {
   sentence.innerHTML += word.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(function() { type(word); }, speed);
  }
}

function backspace(word) {
    if(j<word.length) {
        sentence.innerHTML = sentence.innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
        j++;
        setTimeout(function() { backspace(word); }, speed);
  }
}

function check() {
    if(j < words.length) {
        setTimeout(function() { type(words[j]); }, 1000);
        j++;
        check();
    }
}

check();
```

```css
* {
    font-family: Arial;
  }
  
  .container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .cursor {
    background: #000;
    width: 2px;
    height: 15px;
    animation: blink 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
  }
  
  @keyframes blink {
    to { visibility: hidden; }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Typing Effect Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sentence">We make </div>
        <div class="cursor"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's hard to follow your code as you're manipulating global variables across multiple functions in async operations. I'm going to venture a guess that those `i` and `j` global variables are the culprit. But we might be able to help better if you describe what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: try `j <= words.length-1` on the `check()`

Answer (score 2):

The function you pass to `setTimeout` isn't evaluated until the given duration has expired, as you would expect. At that point, your `j` is going to be `3`, and `words[3]` is undefined. Hence, `(undefined).length` gives you an error.

Open your browser dev tools and run the snippet through stack overflow, then set a breakpoint where the error occurs. This should be your first reaction when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

What the error is saying is not that the *variable* is undefined, but that its *value* is set to `undefined`. A common way to get a value of `undefined` is to access a property/index of an object that is not defined. For example, if your index `j` becomes something outside the bounds of `words`, then `words[j]` will equal `undefined`, so `word.length` will have a type error since there's no `length` property of the value `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable name is "words" and you are parsing "word" please check variable name.

Comment: That is also good that you use const instead of var so that variable save to be  overwrite